# PHP SQL Remove/ignore spaces, tabs etc from search input

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to remove the spaces, whitelines and tabs from the user his input when he searches in the sql database.

So basicly he searches 'Test' (two spaces behind the string) it gives zero results while 'Test' is a correct result in the database. How do I make php / sql use only the word 'Test' as keyword in the sql statement so the result is generated even when the user post spaces before or behind the string. We use a lot of copy and paste when searching so spaces and stuff are in the paste a lot of the time.

I am aware of the questions that are allready here. And I tried all I could implent (as you can see in the overkill tryout..) but none seem to do the trick..

Please help, what am I doing wrong here?

```
$searchresult = trim(filter_var(isset($_POST['usearch10'])?$_POST['usearch10']:'' , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$save = trim(filter_var("%{$_POST['usearch10']}%", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$safedef = trim($save); 

$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE `colomn` LIKE trim(?)");
$stmt2->bind_param("s",$safedef);
$stmt2->execute();
$result = $stmt2->get_result();
while ($obj = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
```

Comment: Never use `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING`

Comment: Can you explain? The result is only text in this case?

Comment: Do you understand what this filter does? Do you know that it will damage your data? Don't use random functions without understanding their purpose

Comment: In my understanding it filters the rare characters etc from the string. All that is accepted are text and numbers no other. So how is this wrong ?

Comment: No, that is not what it does. This filter will look for `<` and `>` and remove anything in between. And it will convert quotes to their HTML entities.

Comment: I am a little offended though that you are assuming I use this filter random without knowing its purpose. I know it could damage data. But in this case it wont as all characters that are exepted are numbers and letters and space in between. So it wont do any harm but will remove all other stuff that is not accepted. That is what I thought and expiercned so far.

Comment: Sorry to offend you, but 99% of people using it don't understand it. Why do you need to remove anything at all? What is the stuff that is accepted and what is that isn't accepted in your opinion? Why do you think quotes need to be encoded to HTML? Also, I am trying to get this filter removed from PHP language as it does more harm than good.

Comment: The reason it is not accepted is easy. I use this filter for my database. A database that contains certain info. The info there is based on other info. That info does not accept those characters and therefor I do not otherwise the one wont correspond with the other. So therefor I use this filter. Just to prevent users from using script tags while backend inserting. Since the data I use this one will never accept < > this is not a problem. And I am sorry for my reaction. I am reacting on the reaction "Don't use random functions without understanding their purpose"

Comment: So any other fucntion that escapes script tags etc will be fine for me. htmlspecialchars for example. But this one worked fine and I, in my case at least, did not see the problem...

Comment: Just a last comment. You are statiing it removes all between the <> tags. In what text based input are those tags needed? Besides coding there is no real need to put stuff between those tags in my opinion. So a developer can choose where to use and where not to use that filter. On regular text input this filter will be fine as there is no need for those tags

Comment: For example, when writing a comment like the one you just did. You used both of these characters.

Comment: Point taken. Allthough this is a website where it is common to use these marks. What filter do you suggest?

Comment: I would suggest no filter. I don't know your business requirements. If it's an integer only then filter for int. Basically, any other filter than the one you are using now would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do two things. One is remove the spaces, and `trim` is enough for that. Unless you're copy-pasting from Microsoft Word, where you could get hidden whitespaces, nonbreaking spaces, and possibly [snakes](https://xkcd.com/1676/). To get rid of **those** you might need to use a regular expression (requiring UTF8/mbstring support),

```
$search = preg_replace('#^\\s*(.*)\\s*$#', '\\1', $search);
```

I am not sure, but maybe if you copy and paste from HTML you might even encounter a " " instead of a space, so you might want to also use `html_entity_decode` (after verifying you need it - it can be quite the source of other troubles).

Then you need to specify an inclusion; do that *after* the filtering, just in case, like this

```
 $search = trim($search);
 $search = "%{$search}%"; // search term anywhere

 WHERE `column` LIKE ?    # You wrote 'colomn' but I assume it was a typo
```

This simply *has* to work, but you could also do it this way:

```
...WHERE `column` LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%');
```

to be sure that MySQL understands what you're trying to tell it.

Try also printing the search term and the query and running it by hand to see what happens. And always check that the query did run successfully. To be even safer, dump the `json_encode($search)`. So, if you forgot a semispace, you'll see not the expected "Test" but something like, if memory serves, "Test\u00a0".

If the absolute worst comes to the worst, activate the *session-level* "general_log" in MySQL and inspect the actual query MySQL gets sent in the MySQL log_file.

Comment: I will try, yeah just a fast typing for the example

Comment: One question though, you are trimming the same variable as you are creating $search. Is this a type or is this the meaning ?

Comment: It is on purpose - I'm just rewriting the variable, so I only have one of them around. Usually I keep two strings called $usrSomestring and $sqlSomestring to remind me of what was sent by the user, and what I need to send to MySQL. Occasionally I may also use $xmlSomestring which is actually HTML and will contain &deg; stuff.

Comment: Thank you, that worked ! Seeing the downvote I asked a dumb question.. But I tried a lot and none where the solution yours is! Thanks again ! I used the answer like this and changed nothing for the sql:   `$searchresult = trim(filter_var(isset($_POST['usearch10'])?$_POST['usearch10']:'' , FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
$searchresult = preg_replace('#^\\s*(.*)\\s*$#', '\\1', $searchresult);
$searchresult = trim($searchresult);
$searchresult = "%{$searchresult}%"; // search term anywhere`

Answer (score 0):

I have never used `trim` in SQL, but if that is changing something or not, your problem could be that you are not searching like `LIKE ”%STRING_TO_SEARCH%"`. `%` at the beginning will tell to match anything before it, and the same character at the end will tell to also match anything after your desired string.